# Android Custom dialog icon

Tags: android

I want to create a custom dialog box like below
but my doubt is about the icon . I want an icon partially outside the layout like  below.How can I achieve that?  I used a Dialog Activity.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This icon is not outside of the layout, it just looks like it is. The trick is that background of the upper part of the layout is set to be fully transparent.

Comment: and how i set the background of the upper part of the layout fully transparent

Comment: By setting its background color to i.e. `#00000000` or using transparent PNG

Comment: but it would affect the whole layout

Comment: You need to make custom layout with background either split into i.e. two vertically stacked frame layouts and the upper one being transparent, or so.